# Convert Over Partition to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, linq

New Question: I've been researching the answer to convert my query to LINQ.

Also tried group by as suggested but could not solve my problem. What I want is to get the row_number that is equal to 1.

The sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.Sku ORDER BY p.Id DESC) ,
        p.Sku
    FROM Product p
    INNER JOIN ProductAttributeCombination pac ON p.Id = pac.ProductId
    WHERE  p.Published = 1
) AS T
WHERE T.RN = 1
```

And the linq:

```
 using (var db = new NopcommerceDbContext())
 {
        var result = (
             from p in db.Products
             from pac in db.ProductAttributeCombinations.Where(pac => p.Id == pac.ProductId).DefaultIfEmpty()
             where p.Published == true
             orderby p.Id descending
             select p
    ).ToList();


       for (var x = 0; x < result.Count; x++)
       {
          Trace.WriteLine($"{ result[x].Sku}");
       }
    }
```

As I said above. I want only 1 row_number from duplicate records.

I tried what @mjwills suggested but i didn't get the result that i want.
When i'm using `First()` it shows nothing.  Same with `FirstDefault()`

Here's my updated code:

```
var items = _context.Products
              .GroupBy(g => g.Sku)
              .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c =>c.Sku).FirstOrDefault());
```

Any tutorial or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Single row (LATEST) from a duplicate SKU sir. I haven't tried that one.

Comment: So you want to `GroupBy` the SKU, and then `OrderByDescending` and `First` to get the first of each SKU?

Comment: Already did sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using LINQ extension methods:

```
  var result = db.Procducts
    .Join(db.ProductAttributeCombinations, p => p.Id, pac => pac.ProductId, (p, pac) => p)
    .Where(p => p.Published == true)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Sku)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  brilliant!... Sorry for my newbie question. I need to study LINQ Extension. Again thank youuu!